# Ocaml syntax error in a simple if-then-else

Tags: if-statement, syntax-error, ocaml, let

I want to change some code written in C into Ocaml

Here is a C code

```
int a, b;
if(m > n)
{
    a = n;
    b = m;
}
else
{
    a = m;
    b = n;
}
```

and I tried to change it into Ocaml but somehow I got a syntax error at the second line.

```
let rec gcd m n =
 if m > n then begin let a = n in; let b = m in end
 else begin let a = m in; let b = n in end
```

What is the problem and how can I fix it?

Comment: The problem is in `let a = n in;`, not `if`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to understand that let declarations are local. That is, when you write `let variable = assignment in expression`, `variable` is only bound in the scope of `expression`

Now when you write `begin let a = n in; let b = m in end`, not only your variable won't be bound outside of the block, but the compiler is still waiting for an expression after both `in` words. You have to remember that unless you're using imperative features of OCaml, `;` is not something you should ever write to indicate subsequent calculations.

Note also that every `let` declaration will create a new variable, so if you type `let a=` in two different places of your code, **this is not the same a**. Hence, the `let` must be *exterior* to your `if` statement:

```
let (a,b) =
 if m > n
 then (n,m)
 else (m,n)
in
the rest of your code
```

Comment: "unless you're using imperative features of OCaml, ; is not something you should ever write." Except in list literals and records. :-)

Comment: @sepp2k indeed :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you wan't, you can do quite the same:

```
let m=3 and n=4 in

let a=ref 0 and b=ref 0 in
if(m > n)
then
(
    a:=n;
    b:=m;
)
else
(
    a:=m;
    b:=n;
);

Printf.printf "a=%d b=%d\n" !a !b;;
```